# Function using <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to make the following images to switch between them when I click in the `<a>` link but it didn't work. When I put the 'onclick' reference in the image it works but not in the link.

Here is the code:

```js
var images=Array("1.png","2.jpg","3.png");
var visibleImage=0;
var a = document.getElementById("link");

function change(img)
{
    visibleImage++;
    if(visibleImage>=images.length)
    {
        visibleImage=0;
    }
    img.src=images[visibleImage];
}
```

The image look like this:

```html
<img src="1.png" onclick="change(this);">
```

The href link is this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="change(this);">Click to change</a>
```

Comment: well `this` isn't an image when element is an `<a>`. What is relationship of image to `<a>`? If there is only one image, give it an id and use that as reference to change src

Comment: The problem is probably that when you put the "onclick" on the img "this" is the image, when you put the "onclick" on the <a>, "this" is the clicked <a>

Comment: I would recommend removing all inline js and moving into script file. Buuut in this - what you wanna do is add a `data` tag, so you have your links set up like `<a href="#" data-target="1.png">Click to change</a>` and then you can manipulate however you see fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `src` attribute of `this`, which is the element you currently interact with (which is `<a>`). You could pass `document.getElementById('image')` in the function, but I think it is better to get it in the function.

**Not changing your function:**

```js
var images=Array("1.png","2.jpg","3.png");
var visibleImage=0;
var a = document.getElementById("link");

function change(img)
{ 
    visibleImage++;
    if(visibleImage>=images.length)
    {
        visibleImage=0;
    }
    img.src=images[visibleImage];
    
    console.log(img.src);
}
```

```html
<img src="1.png" onclick="change(this);" id='image'>
<a href="#" onclick="change(document.getElementById('image'));">Click to change</a>
```

**A more understandable function:**

```js
var images=Array("1.png","2.jpg","3.png");
var visibleImage=0;
var a = document.getElementById("link");

function change()
{ 
    img = document.getElementById("image");
    visibleImage++;
    if(visibleImage>=images.length)
    {
        visibleImage=0;
    }
    img.src=images[visibleImage];
    
    console.log(img.src);
}
```

```html
<img src="1.png" onclick="change();" id='image'>
<a href="#" onclick="change();">Click to change</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This in `<img>` tag is passing itself as a value to the function and because of that it executes without any problem, doing so with an `<a>` tag would pass the anchor tag to the function change.

You should look into Firebug on Mozilla, or plain old 'inspect element' in Chrome's — and some other browsers' — right-click context-menu, to debug the JavaScript and visualize what is being passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use `addEventListener`...

```js
var images = [
  'http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/170/791/welcome-to-the-internet-internet-demotivational-poster-1264714433.png.jpg',
  'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a5/98/1f/a5981fcc09689034ec9dc9201c9787f5.jpg',
  'http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/b3/b3bd9df9b60b8abc7f1253908756964c37e17262e6df6be51bc4a528183e2c96.jpg'
];
  
var visibleImage = 0,
    a = document.querySelector('a'),
    img = document.querySelector('img');

a.addEventListener('click', change, false);

function change() {
  visibleImage++;
  if(visibleImage >= images.length) {
    visibleImage = 0;
  }
  img.src = images[visibleImage];
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click to change</a>
<hr>
<img src="http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/170/791/welcome-to-the-internet-internet-demotivational-poster-1264714433.png.jpg">
```